# After npm install I don't have correct version

Tags: npm, package.json

In my package.json I have `"my-package": ^3.2.1`. I did some changes and I have tag on my-package 3.2.8.

But after I run npm install
`rm -rf package-lock && rm -rf node_modules && npm cache clean --force && npm i`.
I see that again 3.2.1 is downloaded. 8 is ignored. So I need to type the newest number to package.json.

It is happening to me on some projects for about a month. Any idea what can be a cause?

Comment: Are you publishing the package? Is it on the public NPM repo or a private one? Is it showing the correct version when you check it there?

Answer (score -1):

Add the following dependency to your `package.json` file:

`"my-package": "3.2.8" ||"my-package": "^3.2.8"`

and run `npm install` afterwards.